# How to read/write from/to a NTFS formatted External HDD on MacOS high Sierra?

Tags: macos, external-disk, high-sierra, ntfs, apfs

With the introduction of APFS in MacOS high sierra I am unable to read/write from/to my external HDD which is formatted in NTFS. I need this case because I regularly switch between windows and mac and hence want to keep my HDD format as NTFS. Previously (on Sierra) I was using OSX fuse on my mac for NTFS read/write support but they haven't released any update for APFS. Any suggestions or alternatives I can use to achieve NTFS read/write on APFS?

Comment: You seem to be a little confused about what APFS is. It's just another filesystem like HFS+ or NTFS. OSX Fuse allows you to work with filesystems that Apple don't natively support. They aren't going to add APFS support to OSX Fuse because the operating system already natively supports it. Which version of OSX Fuse are you using? This one works perfectly fine with High Sierra. https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/releases

Comment: Ohh, osx fuse stopped working as soon as i updates to high sierra, will try and install is from scratch and see if it works. Thanks for the info.

Comment: FUSE has stopped working for all in recent versions of macOS. Wait until the solution for this to come.

Answer (score 1):

same problem I have faced, I use WD Elements external hard drive on my MacBook Pro which is currently on 10.13.4 I have successfully installed FUSE but it did not work for me.
If you use Seagate/WD Drive then you can download their version of Paragon Software which is available for free but works with their brand's drives only.

[For WD Drives](https://support.wdc.com/knowledgebase/answer.aspx?ID=20717#subject2)

[For Seagate Drives](https://www.seagate.com/in/en/support/downloads/item/ntfs-driver-for-mac-os-master-dl/)